# android dev GoogleDrive API List file. Got them in web browser but 0 when running mobile app

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list file from the user GoogleDrive .. and an get 0 as a listItem size.. strange ... running the request in a web browser I got the item list without any problem :

```
request GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
response : 200 OK
"kind": "drive#fileList",
"etag": "\"G9loKy74Mg0FQ-YRqtCj_yTTrpg/Y1GIIiHUiNqx8F0VZnm_5rCBVTU\"",
"selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse",
 "items": [
{
"kind": "drive#file",
...
```

my android app code ... (standard) running in thread
 Log.d(TAG, "fileList size: " + fileList.getItems().size() )  =>  output 0

did I miss any specific parameters ? (authentication is fine, no claim on the request...)
where can I perform some additional checking on the request/result ?
thanks for help...

```
    private void getDriveContents() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mResultList = new ArrayList<File>();
            Files f1 = mService.files();
            Files.List request = null;              
            do {
                try { 
                    request = f1.list();
                    request.setQ("trashed=false");
                    FileList fileList = request.execute();
                    Log.d(TAG, "fileList size: " + fileList.getItems().size() );
                    mResultList.addAll(fileList.getItems());
                    request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (request != null){
                        request.setPageToken(null);
                    }
                }
            } while (request.getPageToken() !=null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
            populateListView();
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... got the list displayed....
I was using the standard simple_list_item_1  layout on a white bakcground .. ! could not see the text... changed it to a custom textview and it's fine...

btw: I still doesn't understand why the fileList.getItems().size() is giving me 0 ... as obviously I got all the items...